# Installed Rails but the rails command says it's not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm using Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala and Ruby 1.9.1.

I installed Rails using `sudo gem install rails`, which installed all the libraries for me.

When I type `rails` in the terminal it says.

The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
rails: command not found

I can find rake, which is under rake1.9.1, but Rails is nowhere to be found, can someone point me in the right direction?

Edit: path to ruby isn't the problem, the problem is where is rails? how do I execute it? rails just doesn't work, where does the exectuable lives?

Comment: Did you update your PATH variable to include the bin directory of the rails install?

Comment: no.. I didn't, where should I point to? I cannot find its executable.
locate rails returns just links of documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails keeps telling me that it's not currently installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788946/rails-keeps-telling-me-that-its-not-currently-installed)

Comment: Sometimes we face this if we just cloned the app and bundle is remain to install, so just run $ bundle from app root dir will solve this issue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As others say, this may very well be a PATH variable issue on your bashrc/bash_profile file.

[You can learn how to change PATH.](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm).

You can get the current PATH variable by typing `echo $PATH`

Comment: it isnt a problem of putting the path there, it seems rails it not installed at all, how do I check if its really installed? whats its executable? where does it lives?

Comment: Run `gem environment` and you'll find `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY`.

Comment: You ARE GREAT! THANKS TK! Thats exactly what I needed.
It turns out that installing it through gem doesnt create a symlink. I created it and points it to the executable directory. working great

Comment: @rgoytacaz how do you create a symlink?

Comment: @Hlung Use `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/rails /usr/bin/rails` or change it accordingly.

Answer (score 19):

If you're running a rails command *immediately* after installing rails, you will need to restart your terminal before your commands will be recognized.

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13149543/419

Comment: Flagged. I'll be more careful about that. The answer may helpful to those that come across either post (like me), which is why I shared it.

Answer (score 14):

Just had the same issue just put the following in your .bashrc

```
PATH="${PATH}:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/"
```

Comment: PATH="${PATH}:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/"

Answer (score 4):

Assuming **`ruby-2.0.0-p247`** is installed, `rails` is located at following location.

```
prayag@prayag$ ls -l ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/
total 60
-rwxr-xr-x 1 prayag prayag 484 Oct  2 00:20 cap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 prayag prayag 487 Oct  2 00:20 capify
-rwxr-xr-x 1 prayag prayag 475 Oct  1 21:13 erubis
-rwxr-xr-x 1 prayag prayag 469 Oct  1 21:13 rackup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 prayag prayag 480 Oct  1 21:18 rails
-rwxr-xr-x 1 prayag prayag 494 Oct  2 00:27 restclient
-rwxrwxr-x 1 prayag prayag 368 Oct  1 21:10 ruby_executable_hooks
-rwxr-xr-x 1 prayag prayag 467 Oct  2 00:27 sass
-rwxr-xr-x 1 prayag prayag 475 Oct  2 00:27 sass-convert
-rwxr-xr-x 1 prayag prayag 467 Oct  2 00:27 scss
-rwxr-xr-x 1 prayag prayag 487 Oct  1 21:20 sprockets
-rwxr-xr-x 1 prayag prayag 483 Oct  2 00:29 stripe-console
-rwxr-xr-x 1 prayag prayag 467 Oct  1 21:17 thor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 prayag prayag 467 Oct  1 21:20 tilt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 prayag prayag 474 Oct  1 21:16 tt
```

**[1]** `.bash_profile` should already be containing following line, if not add.

```
 [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

**[2]** Add following line to the end of `.bashrc`.

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/"
```

**[3]** Reload `~/.bashrc`

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

**And, it should work.**

Answer (score 3):

If you’re running rbenv you’ll need to run rbenv rehash go get access to the rails-api command.

Answer (score 1):

`gem` should have placed the rails executable script in the same location as ruby's. I'd look in there and make sure the permissions are set correctly and it is executable.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not correct way to resolve this problem. But What I have done is,
I have created a rails.rb file in my executable directory because when I open that directory file was not there and put the following content.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby_noexec_wrapper
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'railties' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first =~ /^_(.*)_$/ and Gem::Version.correct? $1 then
  version = $1
  ARGV.shift
end

gem 'railties', version
load Gem.bin_path('railties', 'rails', version)
```

then I try to run `rails s` in my project and its works..

But before this make sure that executable directory is in your path like I have already in my machine :
`/home/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin:/home/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bin:/home/anand/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin:/home/anand/.rvm/bin`

As per TK said you can get the executable path using `gem environment` command

Answer (score 1):

I added the following lines to my .bashrc file and it worked.

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `rbenv` don't forget add

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

into your `.bash_profile` or other start up scripts.
run `rbenv rehash` is also needed.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to not maintain two different configuration files `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`

It's suggested in this excellent post on the difference between `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` is to source `.bashrc` from your `.bash_profile` file, then putting PATH and common settings in `.bashrc`.

Quoting,

add the following lines to `.bash_profile`:

`if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
source ~/.bashrc
fi`

end quote

Answer (score 0):

I am using macOS and in my case, I needed to add this line to `~/.zshrc`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/exe:$PATH"
```

It can be done like this:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/exe:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

My ruby was installed by brew.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to include the path of Ruby/Jruby folder in your bashrc file. That would ensure that you are able to run it from anywhere.
Don't forget to restart terminal or "source .bashrc" to reload variables in terminals.

Comment: The problem isnt with ruby, ruby works great. But when running rails it says its not installed, although if I do gem list, it will properly show to me, rails 2.3.5

Comment: I looked up the bin folder of my ruby installation. It has a "rails" file. If i rename that to anything else and try to run rails; it doesn't scaffold or create projects..instead says that rails is not installed do sudo apt-get install to install rails.

But if I rename it back to rails; then it starts working. So I am pretty sure that as long as rails is installed properly and you have it in bin folder it should run.

Maybe I haven't installed it as a gem plus I am using JRuby.