# Rails Server and Bundle not Found although they exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

When within a rails project directory (e.g. the directory where I created the app) bundle install returns:

```
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
```

From within the same rails project directory, issuing rails server returns:
    Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

```
  $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

Clearly (below) Rails is installed, Bundle is present, however, I've messed something up so that neither is recognized.

Any ideas where I went wrong?

OSX Lion 10.7.3

Xcode Installed

GCC-10.7-v2.pkg Installed

```
Ruby -v returns:
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]

rvm -v returns:
rvm 1.10.3

rails -v returns:
Rails 3.2.2

env $PATH returns:
env: /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/jsbuilder:/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/command:/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/git/bin/: No such file or directory

RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.17
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-02-16 patchlevel 125) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-darwin-11
- GEM PATHS:
   - /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd
   - /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :benchmark => false
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
   - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: 'bundle install' is two words.

Comment: Let me get this right: `rails server` returns "Rails is not currently installed" but `rails -v` returns "Rails 3.2.2"? Can you double check that, typing them in consecutively on a command line?

Comment: Ben Lee if I'm in a created rails project, rails -v, rails server, etc. says it is not installed, outside of that directory rails -v returns 3.2.2 (of course rails server doesn't work outside a project directory)

Comment: do you have multiple version of ruby installed in your computer?

Comment: I believe I have both 1.8.7 and 1.9.3.  I installed RVM which I believe is linked to 1.9.3.

Comment: If you've got RVM, make sure it's installed properly and in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` or what-have-you. Worst-case scenario, blow away your `~/.rvm` folder and install it again.

Comment: Ben, I have [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" in my .bash_profile, is there anything else I should've included?

Comment: RESOLVED: It turns out I wasn't pointing rvm to the correct place (gemset I think)...after I typed $rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd all was resolved. Found the reference at [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788946/rails-keeps-telling-me-that-its-not-currently-installed)

Answer (score 1):

ruby -v should not give 1.8.7
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
after that it should work just fine