# Upgrading to Ruby 2.0.0 resulted in "Rails is not currently installed on this system"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm, ruby-2.0

I recently upgraded from Ruby 1.9.3 to version 2.0.0. To do so, I used the following command:

```
$ rvm install ruby-2.0.0
$ rvm --default use ruby-2.0.0
```

It successfully installed and set as default ruby-2.0.0; however, when I enter `ruby -v` I encounter the error:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

I know Rails is installed and, before upgrading my version of Ruby, I ran rails -v which returned my current version.

**Attempts to Troubleshoot**

I followed the solution found on [an earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788946/rails-keeps-telling-me-that-its-not-currently-installed) and ran the following commands:

```
gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p374 (found in /Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374)
   (default)
=> global
   rails3tutorial2ndEd

/etc/rvmrc: line 5: install:: command not found
/etc/rvmrc: line 6: update:: command not found

gemsets for ruby-2.0.0-rc1 (found in /Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-rc1)
   (default)
=> global

rvm use ruby-2.0.0-rc1@global
```

However, running `rails -v` again shows that the issue still persists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

Impatience led me to just re-install Rails which fixed the problem. However, I'm still curious if there was a better way of troubleshooting this without (likely unnecessarily) re-installing Rails.

Answer (score 2):

Gemsets in RVM are isolated in that they are only available to a single version of Ruby.  As such, you need to re-install the Rails gem after installing a new version of Ruby.

When a version of Ruby is installed via RVM, 2 associated gemsets will be created simultaneously.  One is called "global" and one is called "default".

Ruby versions (and their *single* associated global gemset) are made active via the `rvm use ruby_version_here` command.

The default or (potentially *multiple*) user generated gemsets are made active via the `rvm use gemset_name_here` command.

Whether a gemset is a global, default, or user generated - it is only available to a single version of Ruby.

Here's a [nice blog post](http://strandcode.com/2013/07/11/ruby-version-manager-rvm-overview-for-rails-newbs/) covering the topic in a bit more detail.