# Rails not installing properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am a noob in rails. I tried to install ruby and rails using `RVM`. Ruby was installed. But when I try to install rails using `gem install rails --version 4.0.0`, I get the following message:

```
Successfully installed rails-4.0.0
Parsing documentation for rails-4.0.0
Done installing documentation for rails after 1 seconds
```

After that

```
rails -v
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
```

I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Rails is 4.0.0. You don't have to specify anything while installing. Just use:

```
gem install rails
```

Also, which version of ruby do you currently have install? The recommended version for rails 4 is Ruby 2.0.0. Can you run `gem list` and see if you can find Rails in the output?

Possible duplicate: [Rails keeps telling me that it's not currently installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788946/rails-keeps-telling-me-that-its-not-currently-installed)

Comment: In gem list i can see rails (4.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

You can get full installation instructions for Rails from [here](http://programming-ror.blogspot.in/2011_09_01_archive.html)

Also use `Ruby 2.0.0` for rails 4

Comment: I have ruby 1.9.2-p320 . Is it compatible with rails 4?

Comment: @Debadatt he was asking "is it compatible...", and i don't think that it's an issue with ruby version at all

Answer (score 0):

you need to use ruby first:

```
rvm use ruby --install
gem install rails -v 4.0.0
```

also make sure to read the outputs of rvm - it will give you notes and warnings when something is wrong