# Rails is not currently installed on this system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

i type:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

but i get this every time:

```
To get the latest version, simply type:
$ sudo gem install rails
```

my ruby version is ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
i try

```
gem install rails
```

but don't worked

Comment: What are the command `which ruby` and `which gem` are giving ?

Comment: RUBY: /Users/Rocela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
GEM: /Users/Rocela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/gem

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788946/rails-keeps-telling-me-that-its-not-currently-installed ?

Comment: If you're using RVM, then you probably should not use `sudo`. Just `gem install rails`. `sudo` will spawn superuser subshell in which RVM is probably not activated.

Comment: yes, but i don't know whats to do when next to i put $ rvm gemset list_all

Comment: Yeah, the sudo command will try to use the ruby that is on your system, and not the rvm one as @SergioTulentsev said. So don't use sudo !

Comment: gem install rails, don't worked :(