# Rails works briefly but then uninstalls itself and says it's not currently installed on this system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, osx-mavericks

Similar to this post on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/820364/ruby-installation-issues-with-rvm), I used [installrails.com](http://installrails.com) to *successfully* set up my ruby on rails environment. I have been able to create a [basic rails application](https://bryanparman-bloccit.herokuapp.com/) and deploy to heroku, but every time I exit terminal and then return and try to start my local server, I get the following message:

```
$ rails s
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

So I try and reinstall rails by using the following command:

```
gem install rails
```

And get this error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/bparman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby
  Reason: image not found
```

So I have tried reinstalling and following the directions on these articles: [Ruby installation issues with RVM](https://superuser.com/questions/820364/ruby-installation-issues-with-rvm) and  [Rails keeps telling me that it's not currently installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788946/rails-keeps-telling-me-that-its-not-currently-installed). Again, these work briefly, and I'm able to update my application, deploy it to Heroku, etc. only to come back 10 minutes later and receive this error message:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system.
```

Here are my ruby installs:

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=> ruby-2.1.3 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.1.4 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Here are my gemsets:

```
$ rvm gemset list_all

gemsets for ruby-2.1.3 (found in /Users/bparman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3)
=> (default)
   global


gemsets for ruby-2.1.4 (found in /Users/bparman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4)
=> (default)
   global
```

Again, as soon as I follow the instructions, it reinstalls, but later will say it's not installed.

Comment: you could be installing rails in one gemset and using other

Comment: Are you sure you are running RVM's rails? Exit terminal, open new session (where 'rails'  command won't work) and call `ruby -v` to check it.

Comment: When I do this I get `ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin13.0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dyld: Library not loaded` message makes me think you might have an out of date homebrew build of libgmp picked up by your rubies.

perhaps try something like

```
> brew update
> brew install gmp 
> rvm reinstall 2.1.4 --disable-binary
```

Comment: I tried this, and again it worked briefly. Then about an hour later I got `Rails is not currently installed on this system.` I created a virtual machine and used the same setup as before and _not_ experiencing the issue in there. I may try getting rid of everything I installed and start fresh.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, turns out that none of the tutorials address the bash profile settings, thats why when you moved to VM and did it afresh it worked.

I simply had to set source for RVM in bash profile took a long time to figure this out.

echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile

Restart terminal and the machine. Never get the error again!!!