# Why can't find rails command after installing rails using gem on FreeBSD?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, freebsd, rbenv

About my environment:

```
FreeBSD: 9.1
```

I have changed my shell from csh to bash:

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

Then edited my ~/.bashrc

```
PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$HOME/local/lib/ruby/gem/bin:$HOME/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

and source it.

I installed ruby by rbenv

```
$ rbenv install 2.0.0
```

After I installed rails

```
$ gem install rails --version 4.0.0
```

I can see it in my gem list

```
$ gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.2.1, 4.0.0)
actionpack (4.2.1, 4.0.0)
actionview (4.2.1)
activejob (4.2.1)
activemodel (4.2.1, 4.0.0)
activerecord (4.2.1, 4.0.0)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activesupport (4.2.1, 4.0.0)
arel (6.0.0, 4.0.2)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.2.2, 3.1.4)
bundler (1.9.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
globalid (0.3.3)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
loofah (2.0.1)
mail (2.6.3, 2.5.4)
mime-types (2.4.3, 1.25.1)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.5.1, 4.3.2)
multi_json (1.11.0)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
polyglot (0.3.5)
psych (2.0.0)
rack (1.6.0, 1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.0.0)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.6)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
railties (4.2.1, 4.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.2.0, 4.0.0)
sprockets (2.12.3)
sprockets-rails (2.2.4, 2.0.1)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (1.2.2, 0.3.43)
```

But when I type

```
$ rails -v
```

it showed me

```
bash: rails: command not found
```

And when I type

```
$ whereis rails
```

it showed me

```
rails:
```

What's wrong about it? How to find the problem?

Comment: Did you try the running the command ina a new terminal?

Comment: @SoorajChandu Yes, but the result was the same.

Comment: Cany you try reinstalling ruby using rvm..i found it more comfotable than rbenv..remember unistalling ruby and rbenv before you install rvm

Comment: @SoorajChandu Thank you for your answer. Is it the key point to solve this issue? Why can't I use rbenv? I want to know where the matter is.

Comment: Maybe this related question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788946/rails-keeps-telling-me-that-its-not-currently-installed

Comment: The only issue I see is the path you specified PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$HOME/local/lib/ruby/gem/bin:$HOME/local/git/bin:$PATH
might be wrong path, everything else looks fine

Comment: @SoorajChandu Thank you. Today I login in my server again. This time when I run `bash` and `gem list`, it showed me a clear list! So I installed rails again and run `rbenv rehash`, it worked! I believe that there were something wrong in the system, but I can't point it out correctly. In fact, I am sure I was under the bash environment yesterday.