# How to run a command automatically after each reboot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu

I currently have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my virtual box. I installed `Ruby and Rails` by RVM. After that I tried

```
$ rails
```

The terminal said

```
The program `rails` is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
 sudo apt install ruby-railties
```

I solve this problem by typing

```
$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Credits [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788946/rails-keeps-telling-me-that-its-not-currently-installed/14903458#14903458)

However, once I reboot the virtual machine, everything I did with source will lose and I need to re-enter

```
 $ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

I also have some similar cases I need to do on every reboot.
So is there any solution can make those command be run automatically each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using bash, add the line to the end your .bashrc:

**.bashrc**

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

If you're using zsh, add it to you .zshrc.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of which implementation of cron you're using it's possible to run jobs only after reboots, for example:

@reboot source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

Again. before editing your crontab make sure your cron implementation supports @reboot flag.

Another option is to include all your scripts in /etc/rc.local