# Rails is not working after restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

When I set up ruby on rails setup on Ubuntu it starts working perfectly but after I restart my PC it gives me error on rails server command as shown:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in \`require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in \`require'
    from /home/muhammad/myapp/one/bin/spring:8:in \`<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in \`load'
    from bin/rails:3:in \`<main>'
```

Comment: Put error text to your question. Don't use pictures for such a case. Especially screenshots of all your desktop...

Comment: /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 from /home/muhammad/myapp/one/bin/spring:8:in `<top (required)>'
 from bin/rails:3:in `load'
 from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Answer (score 0):

Try setting you bash profile as a login console.  I had the same issues to and this fixed it.

Terminal->Edit->Profile Preferences->Title and Command->Run command as a login shell

If that does not fix it check out this post

[Rails keeps telling me that it's not currently installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788946/rails-keeps-telling-me-that-its-not-currently-installed)