# Ran "bundle install," but Rails keeps telling me it can't find a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I tried following the advice here (restarting the terminal) -- [Rails keeps telling me that it's not currently installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788946/rails-keeps-telling-me-that-its-not-currently-installed), but this doesn't seem to work.  Basically in my Rails project I can't start it (or even check the version) because it keeps telling me a gem can't be found.

```
rails -v
...
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.13 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.13
Ignoring websocket-driver-0.6.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine websocket-driver --version 0.6.5
Ignoring websocket-native-1.0.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine websocket-native --version 1.0.0
Could not find nokogiri-1.10.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Then I run

```
bundle install
...
Using spring 2.1.0
Using spring-watcher-listen 2.0.1
Bundle complete! 10 Gemfile dependencies, 50 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

But after restarting the terminal, running "rails -v" still results in the same error.  What to do?

Comment: can you share the output of "gem list" over here

Comment: What are you using to manage your gems? They may be installed, but the project simply isn't looking in the correct location for them on your system.

Comment: run "gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.13" and do bundle