# Cucumber not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I'm trying to run cucumber for the 1st time, but I am getting the following:

```
    /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find cucumber (>= 0) amongst [actionmailer-3.2.6, actionpack-3.2.6, activemodel-3.2.6, activerecord-3.2.6, activeresource-3.2.6, activesupport-3.2.6, arel-3.0.2, builder-3.0.0, bundler-1.1.4, coffee-rails-3.2.2, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.3.3, diff-lcs-1.1.3, erubis-2.7.0, execjs-1.4.0, hike-1.2.1, i18n-0.6.0, journey-1.0.4, jquery-rails-2.0.2, json-1.7.3, mail-2.4.4, mime-types-1.19, multi_json-1.3.6, polyglot-0.3.3, rack-1.4.1, rack-cache-1.2, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.1, rails-3.2.6, railties-3.2.6, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.12, rspec-2.10.0, rspec-core-2.10.1, rspec-expectations-2.10.0, rspec-mocks-2.10.1, rubygems-bundler-1.0.3, rvm-1.11.3.4, sass-3.1.19, sass-rails-3.2.5, sprockets-2.1.3, sqlite3-1.3.6, thor-0.15.3, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.10, tzinfo-0.3.33, uglifier-1.2.5] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1182:in `gem'
    from /opt/local/bin/cucumber:18
```

I've actually got ruby 1.9.3 installed using rvm, and when I do `rvm list`, I get

```
       ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ]
    =* ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
    # => - current
    # =* - current && default
    #  * - default
```

Cucumber was installed using `sudo gem install cucumber`.

So, is there some configuration file for cucumber that i need to change to get it to point to the currently used version of ruby?

I just noticed that my Rails also says that my ruby environment is 1.8.7... I've got Rails 3.2.6 installed.
And I'd definitely created the Rails app after checking that rvm said I was using 1.9.3. 
Perhaps both are related?

Comment: why are you using sudo to install gems? did you install rvm globally?

Comment: It whinged about permissions so I ended up using sudo. How do I tell if it was installed globally or not? I used the RailsInstaller recommended on https://rvm.io/rvm/install/, and it asked for my admin password, so I'm guessing yes. But not sure how to confirm that.

Comment: to check if your ruby is from rvm do `which ruby`. Have you added the required lines to your .bashrc file? Also, use bundler to manage gems.

Comment: Ok, I checked `rvm current` and found that it was still using `system` despite that doing `rvm list` gave the same details as above... Did stuff to it, so now when I check, it comes up with v1.9.2 (decided to use v1.9.2 instead). However, when I do `which ruby`, it still comes up with pointing at `/opt/local/bin/ruby`. Where do I change that detail?

Comment: ismaelga, back on topic, I reinstalled Cucumber after I did my check based on your questions, and it now works, and is pointing at the v1.9.2 version of Ruby. I've still got no idea how to change the `which ruby` bit, and I seem to have a new problem with my actual Rails bit, but at least cucumber works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Its good to see in comment that you have resolved the problem. But for other developer who is facing same problem I am posting this answer. By using `sudo` to install gem creates problem. Here is good instruction given to [install ruby on rails in Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm). And if you will face problem something like command not found 'rails' or 'cucumber'. Then you should first check you path. Here is the answer of [that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954015/installed-rails-but-the-rails-command-says-its-not-installed)