# How to install Rails without using sudo gem install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos-sierra, rbenv

I have installed rbenv using Homebrew.

```
$ rbenv local
2.4.0

$ rbenv global
2.4.0

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

When I check the Rails version I get the following message;

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

I have been told not to install Rails using sudo, so I have tried running `gem install rails` but it gives me the following error;

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen -        /Users/USER1/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thread_safe-0.3.6/.rspec
```

Is it correct that I should not install rails with sudo, and if so how can I?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installed Rails but the rails command says it's not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954015/installed-rails-but-the-rails-command-says-its-not-installed)

Answer (score 0):

I installed RVM (requires download and use of GPG) and followed the steps on RVM's install page.  Should you use sudo? I've read both ways.  Here is the page link:

https://rvm.io/rvm/install

The command once RVM is installed:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

That will install the latest stable version of rails available.  I did this as a complete novice and it has worked for me (as a slightly higher novice) so far.